# QDomNode null element

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have an xml file like this.

```
<root>
  <!--- Comment  -->
  <Info Name="Game" Version="2.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
  <Properties>
    <Logo>path/to/logo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
<root>
```

I want to read the Info tag and its values with qt c++, but the comment is read as null. How can I skip that comment and read the Info tag?

Qt Code

```
QDomDocument xmldoc;
QFile file("./Manifest.xml");

if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    qDebug() << "Failed to open file";
    return;
}

xmldoc.setContent(&file);
file.close();

QDomElement root=xmldoc.documentElement();
QDomElement Identity=root.firstChild().toElement();

if (Identity.isNull()) {
    qDebug() << "Null";
    Identity.nextSibling().toElement();
}

if (Identity.tagName()=="Identity") {
       QString currver=Identity.attribute("Version", "Unknown");
       qDebug() << currver;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Fail";
}
```

Comment: `root.firstChild()` is the comment in your document, not the `Info` element. Thus, `toElement()` returns null because a comment is not an element

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment node is not an element, a null element is returned from `QDomNode::toElement()`. Then, `nextSibling()` is called on a null element, which returns another null element.

You can work with `QDomNode` objects instead of `QDomElement` objects (by dropping `toElement()` calls). That way, the `Info` nodes can be reached normally.

Alternatively, you can use [`QDomDocument::elementsByTagName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#elementsByTagName). The documentation says

> The order of the node list is the order they are encountered in a preorder traversal of the element tree

So the first element of the call `elementsByTagName("Info")` should be the node you need.